# unit test fails in r# but passes in mstest

Tags: resharper, mstest

I'm getting the error below when running Unit Tests in R#, but the tests pass as expected in Visual Studio MSTest, this is occurring with anything that touches the entity framework, other tests work without a problem, i thought this was because a dll was not deployed but made sure that all the dll's are marked as deploy local = true, also made sure that profiling is turned off as I read that this might cause issues with R#, the exception is pretty strange, can't really find any rhyme or reason on why this would be happening. The code executes without a problem as well, so it is really telling me that something is not ok with R# or my configuration of it. Unfortunately, I've tried everything in the MSTest screen in R# with no luck, even using "Run tests with MSTests.exe (not recommended)" and still all tests fail, but only when they deal with the entity framework. Otherwise they will work without a problem. This is happening in other colleagues systems, so it is not my system only.

Test method Calamos.Ccs.Research.Repository.Test.DatabaseContext.EntityFrameworkContexts.ResearchContext

Test.TestFactorPeriod threw exception: System.InvalidOperationException: 
The ForeignKeyAttribute on property 'CountryId' on type 'Calamos.Ccs.Research.Business.Oltp.Geographic.Exchange' is not valid. The navigation property 'Country' was not found on the dependent type 'Calamos.Ccs.Research.Business.Oltp.Geographic.Exchange'. The Name value should be a valid navigation property name.
 at System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Conventions.ForeignKeyPrimitivePropertyAttributeConvention.ForeignKeyAttributeConventionImpl.ApplyNavigationProperty(PropertyInfo propertyInfo, ModelConfiguration modelConfiguration, ForeignKeyAttribute foreignKeyAttribute)
 at System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Conventions.ForeignKeyPrimitivePropertyAttributeConvention.ForeignKeyAttributeConventionImpl.Apply(PropertyInfo propertyInfo, ModelConfiguration modelConfiguration, ForeignKeyAttribute foreignKeyAttribute)   at System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Conventions.AttributeConfigurationConvention`3.System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Conventions.IConfigurationConvention<TMemberInfo,TConfiguration>.Apply(TMemberInfo memberInfo, Func`1 configuration)   at System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Conventions.ForeignKeyPrimitivePropertyAttributeConvention.System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Conventions.IConfigurationConvention.Apply(PropertyInfo memberInfo, Func`1 configuration)
 at System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Configuration.ConventionsConfiguration.ApplyPropertyConfiguration(PropertyInfo propertyInfo, ModelConfiguration modelConfiguration)
 at System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Mappers.TypeMapper.MapStructuralElements(Type type, ICollection`1 annotations, Action`2 propertyMappingAction, Boolean mapDeclaredPropertiesOnly, Func`1 structuralTypeConfiguration)
 at System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Mappers.TypeMapper.MapEntityType(Type type)
 at System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Mappers.NavigationPropertyMapper.Map(PropertyInfo propertyInfo, EdmEntityType entityType, Func`1 entityTypeConfiguration, Type sourceType)
 at System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Mappers.PropertyMapper.Map(PropertyInfo propertyInfo, EdmEntityType entityType, Func`1 entityTypeConfiguration, Type sourceType)
 at System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Mappers.TypeMapper.<>c_*DisplayClass12.b*_e(PropertyMapper m, PropertyInfo p)
 at System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Mappers.TypeMapper.MapStructuralElements(Type type, ICollection`1 annotations, Action`2 propertyMappingAction, Boolean mapDeclaredPropertiesOnly, Func`1 structuralTypeConfiguration)
 at System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Mappers.TypeMapper.MapEntityType(Type type)
 at System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Mappers.NavigationPropertyMapper.Map(PropertyInfo propertyInfo, EdmEntityType entityType, Func`1 entityTypeConfiguration, Type sourceType)
 at System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Mappers.PropertyMapper.Map(PropertyInfo propertyInfo, EdmEntityType entityType, Func`1 entityTypeConfiguration, Type sourceType)
 at System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Mappers.TypeMapper.<>c__DisplayClass12.<MapEntityType>b__e(PropertyMapper m, PropertyInfo p)
 at System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Mappers.TypeMapper.MapStructuralElements(Type type, ICollection`1 annotations, Action`2 propertyMappingAction, Boolean mapDeclaredPropertiesOnly, Func`1 structuralTypeConfiguration)
 at System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Mappers.TypeMapper.MapEntityType(Type type)
 at System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Mappers.NavigationPropertyMapper.Map(PropertyInfo propertyInfo, EdmEntityType entityType, Func`1 entityTypeConfiguration, Type sourceType)
 at System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Mappers.PropertyMapper.Map(PropertyInfo propertyInfo, EdmEntityType entityType, Func`1 entityTypeConfiguration, Type sourceType)
 at System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Mappers.TypeMapper.<>c_*DisplayClass12.b*_e(PropertyMapper m, PropertyInfo p)
 at System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Mappers.TypeMapper.MapStructuralElements(Type type, ICollection`1 annotations, Action`2 propertyMappingAction, Boolean mapDeclaredPropertiesOnly, Func`1 structuralTypeConfiguration)
 at System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Mappers.TypeMapper.MapEntityType(Type type)
 at System.Data.Entity.DbModelBuilder.<>c__DisplayClass7.<MapTypes>b__1(Type type)
 at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereListIterator`1.MoveNext()
 at System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Utilities.IEnumerableExtensions.Each(IEnumerable`1 ts, Action`1 action)
 at System.Data.Entity.DbModelBuilder.MapTypes(EdmModel model)
 at System.Data.Entity.DbModelBuilder.Build(DbProviderManifest providerManifest, DbProviderInfo providerInfo)
 at System.Data.Entity.DbModelBuilder.Build(DbConnection providerConnection)
 at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.CreateModel(LazyInternalContext internalContext)
 at System.Data.Entity.Internal.RetryLazy`2.GetValue(TInput input)
 at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeContext()
 at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.GetEntitySetAndBaseTypeForType(Type entityType)
 at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Initialize()
 at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.get_InternalContext()
 at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1.System.Linq.IQueryable.get_Provider()
 at System.Linq.Queryable.FirstOrDefault(IQueryable`1 source, Expression`1 predicate)
 at Calamos.Ccs.Research.Repository.Test.DatabaseContext.EntityFrameworkContexts.ResearchContextTest.TestFactorPeriod()in ResearchContextTest.cs: line 290

Comment: What version of Resharper / Visual studio are you using? Could it be something wierd to do with 32/64 bit compilation of your code?

Comment: I'm running Visual Studio 2010 and R# 7.0, which seems to be the latest downloadable version from Jetbrains, the solution configuration is set to Any which is usually what we run in. Using Mixed platform with x86 doesn't seem to work either, it certainly seems to be one of those issues, just haven't been able to track it down yet, even looking at procmon I didn't see anything out of the ordinary there.